# App Engine and flask fails to get post message from webhook

Tags: flask, google-app-engine, paypal, webhooks

I'm doing a webhook request from [Paypal webhook simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/webhooksSimulator) to an App Engine service, developped in flask.

The webservice has a route to get webhooks using this simple code in flask:

```
@app.route('/webhook',methods = ['POST'])
def webhook():
    
    print(request.method )
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.json)
        
        return 'success', 200
    else:
        abort(400)
```

Unfortunatelly, the request doesn't work, and there is no log message from the flask app, not even from the print(request.method).

[Picture of Web hook test failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWFfc.png)

Webhooks URL:

```
https://www.mywebsite/webhook
```

After sending test, I have the following event status:

```
Your event failed to queue at May 13 2022, 20:28:47
```

Error details:

```
{}
```

Do you know why the webhook test isn't working?

Answer (score -2):

The error comes from the sandbox account created by default. When starting a sandbox service, Paypal creates a default account that doesn't have all the functions, including the webhook one. I've created a new sandbox account and the webhook works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).